# Reload Vaadin application

Tags: java, vaadin

How can I reload Vaadin application on button click?

I read that adding? Restart Application to URL will restart it, but which method call?

Comment: Do you want to do exactly the same thing as restartApplication or just refresh the main window ?

Comment: I wanna to reload whole application, when i update code to tomcat on reload button i wanna to make changes to app, not to close whole application and start browser again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for but you can use the close method from the [Application class](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/Application.html)

```
public void close()
```

In effect this will cause the application stop returning any windows when asked. When the application is closed, its state is removed from the session and the browser window is redirected to the application logout url set with setLogoutURL(String). If the logout url has not been set, the browser window is reloaded and the application is restarted.

Answer (score -1):

Just put the content of your choice in the mainwindow:

```
//add listener to button

sendButton.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

 public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

//reload page

  mainWindow.setContent(buildUserPage());

 }
}
```